# Characterizing a non -normal distribution of data

Tags: distributions, data-transformation

I have a data set with about 3000 members that I'd like to use as a feature for a binary classification algorithm. The variable seems to be skewed by nature because the histogram is tailed at pretty much any sample. Below is the current population:

[image]

So I have a few questions that hope those of you who are much more experienced might be able to help with.

- Can I "fit" these data to a more suitable distribution than a normal one? Perhaps a chi square?
- For a non-normal distribution, especially a tailed one like mine, is there something analogous to standard deviation that I can use to characterize a data point?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: after posting, I realized I meant to add gamma as a potential fit

Comment: There are many relatively heavy-tailed, right-skewed distributions. Sometimes it is useful to identify the 'name' of such a distribution (in order to have a functional for for the PDF or CDF and to do inference), and sometimes not. // You might add Weibull, Rayleigh, and lognormal to your list of right-skewed distributions with support $(0, \infty).$

Comment: 1. Why would you need to identify a distribution if you're planing to use this as a feature? Aren't you just conditioning on it anyway? 2. It's unclear to me what you mean by "tailed at pretty much any sample"; you only appear to have *one* sample, and it's not clear to me what you intend by "tailed".

Answer (score 0):

FYI I was able to find a fitting algorithm with the following results:

[image]

Turns out that the best fit is "Inverse Gaussian"!

Now I need to gain an understanding of the parameters.